# Access violation when using std::vector

Tags: c++, stdvector

I'm getting the following error:

- Unhandled exception at 0x012a4bd9 in TBG.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0000002c.

Pointing to the size() method of vector.h. It seems to happen when this method is used:

```
void Player::printInventory(){
    if(inventory.size() != 0){
        for(unsigned int i=0; i<inventory.size(); i++){
            cout<<inventory[i] << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

---

Full code:

Player.h:

```
#pragma once
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

class Player
{
private:
    int health;
    string name;
    vector<int> inventory;

public:
    Player(void);
    Player(string);
    ~Player(void);
    void changeHealth(int);
    void addToInventory(int);
    void removeFromInventory(int);
    void printInventory();
};
```

Player.cpp:

```
#include "Player.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>

Player::Player(void)
{
    health = 20;
}

Player::Player(string newName)
{
    name = newName;
    health = 20;
}

Player::~Player(void)
{
}

void Player::changeHealth(int amount){
    health += amount;
}

/*void Player::addToInventory(int item){
    inventory.push_back(item);
}

void Player::removeFromInventory(int itemID){

    for(unsigned int i=0; i<inventory.size(); i++){
        if(inventory[i] == itemID)
            inventory.erase(inventory.begin()+i);
    }

}*/

void Player::printInventory(){
    if(!inventory.empty()){
        for(unsigned int i=0; i<inventory.size(); i++){
            cout<<inventory[i] << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

main:

```
#include "World.h"
#include "Player.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

World world;

void main(){

    unique_ptr<Player> player(new Player("Ted"));
    world.setPlayer(move(player));
    int selection = 0, inventoryOption = 0, exitOption = 0;

    do{
        inventoryOption = 0;
        exitOption = inventoryOption + 1;

        cout<< inventoryOption <<". View Inventory"<<endl;
        cout<< exitOption <<". Quit game";

        cin>>selection;

        if(selection == inventoryOption){
            player->printInventory();
        }
        else{
        }


    }while(selection != exitOption);

}
```

Please excuse the messiness, this code is butchered from previous code which has the same errors.

Comment: Can you include more context?  A snippet that compiles and includes the declaration of inventory would be the best.

Comment: Need more context. Context of usage please.

Comment: I think the `Player` is probably being allocated incorrectly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're `move`ing the `unique_ptr` so that it no longer points to the `new Player`, then you're using it:

```
world.setPlayer(move(player));

...

player->printInventory();
```

Don't use `move` just to make the code compile; use `shared_ptr` so you can have multiple pointers to the object.

Answer (score 1):

Use !inventory.empty() instead inventory.size() != 0.
So, for code, when you move unique_ptr, unique_ptr will be release, so it`ll point to zero.

Comment: Okay, I'll post the Player class now

Comment: `inventory.size() != 0` is just fine. The problem must be elsewhere.

Comment: @EitanT yeah, but use inventory.empty() for detect that vector is empty better, than inventory.size() == 0 and in this code condition is unnecessary.

Comment: @ForEveR And why is it better exactly?

Comment: @EitanT because function empty created for this.

Comment: @EitanT so that when you change to `list`, you still have an `O(1)` algorithm instead of `O(n)`. It's also suggested in Effective STL.

Comment: I think @EitanT's point here is that `size` vs `empty` has nothing to do with the _OP's actual problem_.

Comment: Anyway, I think this should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: @ildjarn You said it before I did.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using some null object. Print the value of this(Player) in the function just before the crash.